# Change TextView's height programatically on ViewPager's change

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, resize

I am using a `ViewPager` with 4 `Fragment`s as some kind of intro/manual for my app. My problem is when I reach the last Fragment, which looks like this:[image]

When the user clicks the "Ready" `Button` I have an animation to "collapse" the Title (change it's height to 0px) and do some other stuff. My intention is to reset the view to it's original state ("expand" Title) when the user navigates out to another Fragment of the ViewPager.

To know when the user moves to another page I am using `setUserVisibleHint` like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if( !isVisibleToUser) {
        // Reset/expand the title's TextView
        if(mTitle != null) {
            int titlesHeight = mTitle.getMeasuredHeight();

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTitle.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = titlesHeight;

            mTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            mTitle.invalidate();
            mTitle.requestLayout();
        }
        // Reset other views...
    }   
}
```

But this doesn't work.

## What I've tried

I have tried every possible combination of `setLayoutParams` , `invalidate` and `requestLayout`   including leaving one or more out and changing their order, but when the user navigates back to the fourth page the Title is still collapsed.
I have checked that this method is correctly triggered and that `titlesHeight != 0` every single time and that `getText`still returns "Title".
I reset other View's (which I'm not showing for the sake of simplicity) like the `Chronometer` shown in my screenshot and everything is fine.

### onPageSelected and Interface

Interface

```
public interface FragmentAdapterNotificator {
    public void fragmentIsVisible();
    public void fragmentIsNotVisible();
}
```

mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()

```
Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    FragmentAdapterNotificator fragment = (FragmentAdapterNotificator) mAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, i);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.fragmentIsVisible();
    }
}
```

Fragment implementing Interface

```
public class FragmentFour extends Fragment implements FragmentAdapterNotificator {
    @Override
        public void fragmentIsVisible() {
            // Reset/expand the title's TextView
            if(mTitle != null) {
                int titlesHeight = mTitle.getMeasuredHeight();

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTitle.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = titlesHeight;

                mTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
                mTitle.invalidate();
                mTitle.requestLayout();
            }
        }
}
```

Someone has a clue on what's going on here?

## Note

I DON'T want to use another `Animation` to expand the Title because if the user is in another page then there's no point in animating the height's restore because the user won't see it so I think that in terms of performance it is better to use the "shortcut" to avoid the animation.
I have tried to use an "expand" Animation just for testing and it works fine, but I don't want to use it.

## Appendix

Here is my fragment's layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:padding="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextTitle"
        android:text="@string/tour_four_title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ready"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="READY" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Some Stuff -->        
</LinearLayout>
```

"Collapse" animation used to animate the Title's height to 0:

```
public void collapseView(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(800);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

"Expand" animation:

```
public void expandView(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(1000);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

It's pretty much the same as my "reset" method, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

SO basically ,from what i understand you want the Title to go back to its original height when the user navigates away from the page. Rather than that why dont you make it to default when the user is coming back to the original fragment. Let me explain, You make the Title to 0dp on the click of the button , the user navigates away and when he comes to the fragment again the Title should be 20dp ,Right?

This can be done like this i guess,

Make an interface in your basic_activity(Where the viewpager is declared) something like

```
 public interface FragmentInterface{
       void Fragmentbecamevisible();
}
```

Now declare setOnPageChangeListener to your viewPager,

```
 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            FragmentInterface frag=(FragmentInterface)mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, arg0);
            if(frag!=null)
            {
                frag.Fragmentbecamevisible();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Now what it does is,this interface function will be called each time the user navigates to a fragment.

Implement the interface in all the fragments.
Make changes to the function in the fragment you want the animation to happen.

So it will be like,

```
public class Your_Fragment extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface
{
    public void Fragmentbecamevisible() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Do all the things with the TITLE here ..Iv done the same with a button.So you will be able to change the color and height of Title in here


}


}
//Rest of the codes as well

}
```

So each time you navigate into the fragment the user will see the original structure .

Hope this method works.

Please make edits wherever needed.

Comment: It doesn't work, the result is still the same (TextView's height is still 0dp) :(

Comment: @peguerosdc ..what happened when you tried .. try putting a Toast in the Fragment interface function to make sure the function is called when the swipe takes place.

Comment: I have edited my question :) and I am sure that the function is called because, as I said, I reset other views (like the Chronometer) and thery are correctly reseted. However, your proposal resets the Fragment when the user navigates back to it, but because I am using a ViewPager I need the fragment to be reseted when the user navigates away from it because of the scroll.

Comment: @peguerosdc ..ok..while user navigates away..i think i have a solution for that .wait a minute.. meanwhile in the existing code.. why dont you set the text again in the fragment interface function along with setTextSize and setHeight ...

Comment: I'll wait, thanks :). And setting the text again doesn't work neither.

Comment: for resetting while navigating away .im not so sure about that,let me check. But this got to work ,cause im working on something very similar and using this . Try getting the TextView inside the function again like TextView tx=(TextView)getActivity.findViewbyId(R.id.textview);  and set the text ,height and textsize again. Dont use the if condition and all,make it very simple and try first.

Comment: I tried 
TextView title = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.title); and
TextView title = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);
And still no luck. It's funny because when using "onPageSelected" and a hardcoded height like 1500 (much bigger than needed) my View is resized correctly when the user navigates to it for the very first time, but at the second time it fails.

Comment: I figured it out. I posted the solution and well, let's say that I am not too smart jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Feel really stupid, but in "collapseView" I have this

```
if(interpolatedTime == 1){
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

So my view is resized in my reset method but as it is GONE I can't see it. I just modified it's visiblity and voila:

```
// Reset/expand the title's TextView
if(mTitle != null) {
    int titlesHeight = mTitle.getMeasuredHeight();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTitle.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = titlesHeight;
    mTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
    mTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```